# R sweep on a Sparse Matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I'm attempting to apply the `sweep` function to a sparse matrix (`dgCMatrix`). Unfortunately, when I do that I get a memory error. It seems that sweep is expanding my sparse matrix to a full dense matrix.

If there an easy way to perform this function without if blowing up my memory?

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
sparse_matrix <- sweep(sparse_matrix, 1, vector_to_multiply, '*')
```

Comment: assuming that the length of  `vector_to_multiply` equals the number of rows of  `sparse_matrix`, you might be able to do `sparse_matrix* vector_to_multiply`

Answer (score 5):

I'm working with a big and very sparse `dgTMatrix` matrix (200k rows and 10k columns) in a NLP problem. After hours thinking in a good solution, I created an alternative `sweep` function for sparse matrices. It is very fast and memory efficient. It took just 1 second and less than 1G of memory to multiply all matrix rows by a array of weights. For `margin = 1` it works for both `dgCMatrix` and `dgTMatrix`.

Here it follows:

```
sweep_sparse <- function(x, margin, stats, fun = "*") {
   f <- match.fun(fun)
   if (margin == 1) {
      idx <- x@i + 1
   } else {
      idx <- x@j + 1
   }
   x@x <- f(x@x, stats[idx])
   return(x)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I second @user20650's recommendation to use direct multiplication of the form `mat * vec` which multiplies every column of your matrix `mat` with your vector `vec` by implicitly recycling `vec`.

### Processing time profiling

I understand that you're main requirement here is memory, but it's interesting to perform a `microbenchmark` comparison of the `sweep` and direct multiplication methods for both a dense and sparse matrix:

```
# Sample data
library(Matrix)  
set.seed(2018)
mat <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 10^6, replace = T), nrow = 10^3)
mat_sparse <- Matrix(mat, sparse = T)
vec <- 1:dim(mat)[1]

library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    sweep_dense = sweep(mat, 1, vec, '*'),
    sweep_sparse = sweep(mat_sparse, 1, vec, '*'),
    mult_dense = mat * vec,
    mult_sparse = mat_sparse * vec
)
res
Unit: milliseconds
         expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq      max
  sweep_dense   8.639459  10.038711  14.857274  13.064084  18.07434  32.2172
 sweep_sparse 116.649865 128.111162 162.736864 135.932811 155.63415 369.3997
   mult_dense   2.030882   3.193082   7.744076   4.033918   7.10471 184.9396
  mult_sparse  12.998628  15.020373  20.760181  16.894000  22.95510 201.5509

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

On average the operations involving a sparse matrix are actually slightly slower than the ones with a dense matrix. Note however, how direct multiplication is faster than `sweep`.

### Memory profiling

We can use `memprof` to profile the memory usage of the different approaches.

```
library(profmem)
mem <- list(
    sweep_dense = profmem(sweep(mat, 1, vec, '*')),
    sweep_sparse = profmem(sweep(mat_sparse, 1, vec, '*')),
    mult_dense = profmem(sweep(mat * vec)),
    mult_sparse = profmem(sweep(mat_sparse * vec)))
lapply(mem, function(x) utils:::format.object_size(sum(x$bytes), units = "Mb"))
#$sweep_dense
#[1] "15.3 Mb"
#
#$sweep_sparse
#[1] "103.1 Mb"
#
#$mult_dense
#[1] "7.6 Mb"
#
#$mult_sparse
#[1] "13.4 Mb"
```

To be honest, I'm surprised that the memory imprint of the direct multiplication with a sparse matrix is not smaller than that involving a dense matrix. Perhaps the sample data are too simplistic. It might be worth exploring this with your actual data (or a representative subset thereof).

Comment: In your example, the sparse matrix isn't really sparse (50%); if you increase the sparsity the relative speed & memory will improve

Comment: Thanks @user20650; if/when I have some spare time I'll try to come up with a more representative example.

Comment: Fantastic answers. Thank you both. I learned quite a few things.